# Optimizing implementation of custom ULID generation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, plpgsql

Following the spec [github.com/ulid/spec](https://github.com/ulid/spec)
I'm trying to implement this on Postgres, with some tweaks (without monolitic implementation, no base32):

- 43 bits allocated to timestamp instead of 48
- 85 bits allocated to randomness instead of 80

This function is planned to replace uuid generator.
I'm beginner but all theses casts and allocating each byte one by one seems dirty, any way to optimize this ?
Should I switch into C ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_custom_ulid() RETURNS bytea AS $$
DECLARE
    unix bit(43);
    --gen_random_bytes from pgcrypto extension
    random_bytes bytea = gen_random_bytes(11);
    ulid bytea = '\x00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00';
BEGIN
    unix := (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp())*1000)::bigint::bit(43);

    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 0, (unix)::bit(8)::integer);
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 1, (unix << 8)::bit(8)::integer);
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 2, (unix << 16)::bit(8)::integer);
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 3, (unix << 24)::bit(8)::integer);
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 4, (unix << 32)::bit(8)::integer);
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 5, ((unix << 40)::bit(3)||GET_BYTE(random_bytes,0)::bit(5))::bit(8)::integer);
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 6, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 1));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 7, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 2));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 8, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 3));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 9, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 4));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 10, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 5));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 11, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 6));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 12, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 7));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 13, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 8));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 14, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 9));
    ulid := SET_BYTE(ulid, 15, GET_BYTE(random_bytes, 10));

    RETURN ulid;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the functions provided by [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.9) or [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html#id-1.11.7.53.4)? Or if you want something "sorted", you could use [sequential-uuid](https://github.com/tvondra/sequential-uuids)

Comment: Nothing, they create UUID not ULID. I like the idea behing ULID.

Comment: I will take a look to [sequential-uuid](https://github.com/tvondra/sequential-uuids), thanks